# How to get post type information?

Tags: custom-post-types

So, I'm doing some theme and plugin integration and stumbled upon ome issues with my breadcrumb. Basically my theme has a function that checks for certain post types and then populates the breadcrumb accordingly.

Some of my plugins are unknown to the theme, so now I'm manually adding those post types to the breadcrumb method. The thing is, when viewing a certain page I sometimes have no clue on which conditional to use is_singular(), is_post_type_archive() and what the post type is actually named for a certain plugin.

I'm wondering if there's some sort of (debug) function within Wordpress that tells me some meta-data of the request.

Answer (score 1):

> I sometimes have no clue on which conditional to use is_singular(), is_post_type_archive() and what the post type is actually named for a certain plugin

[`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) will return true on any single post page

> - This conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed, which is the case when one of the following returns true: `is_single()`, `is_page()` or `is_attachment()`. If the `$post_types` parameter is specified, the function will additionally check if the query is for one of the post types specified.

[`is_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) will return true when the srchive page is being viewed of a custom post type

> -Checks if the query is for an archive page of a given post type(s).

As for code, you can always use the `$post` global and then use that to check the post type of the given post. On archive pages, `$post` should always contain the post object of the last post in a query.

Something like following will work:

```
global $post;
// Get all the custom post types
$args = [
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false
];
$post_types = get_post_types( $args ); 

$single_post_type = $post->post_type;

// For single post pages
if ( is_single() ) { // Or you can use is_singular()
    // Only display post type name if post type is not build in type
    if ( in_array( $single_post_type, $post_types ) ) {
        echo $single_post_type;
    }
}

// For single post type archives
if ( is_post_type_archive ) { 
    echo $single_post_type;
}
```